# Property Change event is null even after I registered it

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify class when there is any change in a variable of a particular object within it.

Below is the class:

```
 public class MyClass
 {
        public SecClass MyObj { get; set; }

     //A few more variables
 }
```

SecClass:

```
 public class SecClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    private bool _noti= false;

    public bool Noti
    {
        get { return _noti; }
        set
        {
            _noti= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Noti");
        }
    }

     //A few more variables
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
       }
    }
 }
```

Here my function that makes the event registration:

```
    public void Register()
    {
      MyObj.PropertyChanged += MyObj_PropertyChanged;         
    }
```

Function works and the registration is done, but when it comes to change it displays the `Property Change` as null (I guess that somewhere registration deleted, before happens change, how can I check this?)

Comment: Show some code please where you register the eventhandler

Comment: @bash.d you mean like the `Register` method?

Comment: The code where you create your object and initialize it

Comment: My guess would be you're changing the property after the registration, or you're changing the instance of the MyObj property somewhere. You also have a redundant cast.

Comment: @devdigital since the `PropertyChanged` declaration <s>isn't</s> *wasn't* shown, we <s>can't</s> *couldn't* actually say whether the cast is redundant or not, hence the last line in my answer (wondering whether it is actually doubly-implemented, which *could* cause a problem)

Comment: @devdigital. I had a few errors in question, I fixed (I added the definition of the event, and I deleted the unnecessary cast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hooked this together with:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var c = new MyClass();
        c.MyObj = new SecClass();
        c.Register();
        c.MyObj.Noti = !c.MyObj.Noti;
    }
}
```

adding (for illustration):

```
private void MyObj_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);
}
```

to `MyClass`, and:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

to `SecClass` (to get them to compile), and it works fine - printing `"Noti"` at runtime. There *is* a theoretical thread-race, but it is *very* unlikely in any sane usage, but recommended usage is:

```
var handler = PropertyChanged;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

Also, for info: if you add `[CallerMemberName]` to that, you don't need to specify the property explicitly:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) {...}
```

with:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(); // the compiler adds the "Noti" itself
```

But fundamentally: "cannot reproduce" - it works fine. I wonder if maybe it relates to your `PropertyChanged` implementation, since you don't actually show that. In particular, I wonder if you actually have ***two*** events: one explicitly implemented. That would mean that it is getting treated differently by your cast.